# Linux Kernel Header File Location

Tags: linux-kernel, header

I am running a linux OS.

I want to know the locations of the header files.

I have tried the following :-

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

But there are only two .ko files inside it. I expected results which include folders like build(which contains the include folder, which inturn consists of the header files)

I have even tried doing this :-

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-($uname -r)
```

Output

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-kernel-3.8.13-OpenNetworkLinux-e500mc-1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-kernel-3.8.13-OpenNetworkLinux-e500mc-1.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

now look in "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build"